# Dificuldade em fazer programa gerador de números de loteria

Tags: python-3.x

Estou fazendo um trabalho de python, porém estou apanhando muito na parte de separar os números em impar, par e primos e gerar números aleatórios dessas categorias. Vou colocar como está meu código até o momento e como é a atividade.

Como está meu codigo:

```
from random import randint

escolhaJogo = 0
quantidadeNumeros = 0
jogosQuantidade = 1
tipoNumero = 0
listaNumeros =[]

while (escolhaJogo == 1 or 2):
    print("Escolha seu jogo")
    escolhaJogo = int(input("Digite 1 - Mega Sena 2 - Dupla Sena: "))  
    if (escolhaJogo == 1):
        tipoJogo = "voce esta concorrendo a Mega Sena"
        break
    elif (escolhaJogo == 2):
        tipoJogo = "voce esta concorrendo a Dupla Sena"
        break

jogosQuantidade = int(input("Digite a quantidade de jogos: "))

while True:
    quantidadeNumeros = int(input("Digite a quantidade de numero gerados(entre 6 a 15): "))
    if quantidadeNumeros >= 6  and quantidadeNumeros <= 15:  
        break

while (tipoNumero == "primo" or "par" or "impar"):
    if (tipoNumero == "par"):
        
    elif (tipoNumero == "impar"):

    elif (tipoNumero == "primo"):


print(tipoJogo)
print(jogosQuantidade)
print(quantidadeNumeros)
```

a)  Consultar o usuário para que informe qual Loteria deseja gerar números:
se 1: MEGA SENA ou 2: DUPLA SENA;

b)  Consultar o usuário para que informe a quantidade de jogos;

c)  Consultar o usuário sobre a quantidade de números a serem gerados por
jogo (o programa deve gerar de 6 a 15 números por jogo);

d)  Deverá ser possível especificar se os números que serão gerados
aleatoriamente são pares, ímpares ou primos e, ainda, se há algum número fixo que
deve fazer parte do conjunto gerado;

e)  Os números devem ser gerados de forma aleatória a partir de uma
função e devem ser armazenados em listas (uma por jogo).

A figura abaixo apresenta um exemplo das informações que devem ser solicitadas ao
usuário.

[image: A figura abaixo apresenta um exemplo das informações que devem ser solicitadas ao usuário.]

Comment: Exatamente qual é a pergunta?

Comment: para fazer a separação de par/ímpar use o % que é o resto da divisão.                   se x % 2 == 0; x é par. procure sobre a biblioteca random

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Gerar um número par / impar / primo:**

Parar gerar um número aleatório você pode usar o biblioteca ***random*** com *random.randrange()*. Basicamente ele gera um número aleatório dentre de um intervalo de números. Por exemplo:

```
import random

random.randrange(1,6)
#Ele vai gerar um número de 1 a 5

random.randrange(1,17)
#Ele vai gerar um número de 1 a 16
```

Para verificar se ele é par ou impar você pode usar o Módulo:

```
#Retorna o resto da divisão entre operandos

10 % 2 = 0
#10 / 2 = 5
#Resto da divisão é 0

11 % 2 = 1
#11 / 2 = 5.5
#Resto da divisão é 1
```

Com isso podemos verificar se ele é par ou impar:

(Você pode estudar sobre operadores python [aqui](https://www.devmedia.com.br/operadores-no-python/40693))

```
n = random.randrange(1,11)
#Gerar um número aleatório entre 1 e 10

modulo = n % 2

if modulo == 0:
    print('Ele é par')
else:
    print('Ele é ímpar')
```

Parar verificar se o número é primo você pode criar um *list* e verificar se o número gerado está dentro desta *list*:

(Um pouco sobre *list* [aqui](https://www.devmedia.com.br/como-trabalhar-com-listas-em-python/37460))

```
primos=[1,2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47]
#Números primos

if n in primos:
    print('Ele é primo')
```

---

**2. Quantidades de Jogos / Números (Loop)**

Você pode *while* para gerar certo número de jogos:

```
n_jogos = input('Número de jogos...')
jogos_gerados = 0

while n_jogos != jogos_gerados:
    jogos_gerados += 1
    
    #Suas Funcoes...
```

Resumindo enquanto o *jogos_gerados* nâo atingir o *n_jogos* requerido ele persistirá nesse *Loop*

(Artigo sobre *[while](https://www.devmedia.com.br/python-estrutura-de-repeticao-while/38546)*)

---

**3. Guardar Informações dos jogos**

Você pode usar *list* para guardar números gerados e *dictionaries* para guardar essa *list* de cada jogo:

```
lista_jogos = {

    #Armazenando Resultados dos Jogos    

    jogo1 = [2,6,1,8,3],
    jogo2 = [6,8,3,7,6]
        #Armazenando Números gerados
}
```

Para cada número gerado você pode armazenar ele usando método *list.append()*:

```
lista = [1,2]
lista.append(3)

print(lista)
#[1,2,3]
```

E parar armazenar esses jogos:

```
dict = {}
dict['jogo1'] = [1,5,7,2,3]

print(dict)
#{'jogo1': [1,5,7,2,3]}
```

**PS: Se Você entender inglês você pode estudar um pouco sobre [Python](https://www.w3schools.com/python/default.asp), é um execelente site para começar a estudar Python**

Comment: O objetivo do site não é fazer a tarefa de casa dos usuários. Ao fazer isso você não está ajudando a pessoa.

Comment: Devo excluir a minha resposta?

Comment: Agora não, pois está bem escrita e deu um trabalhão para fazer. Mas evite responder quando houver indícios de ser tarefa de casa ou quando a pergunta soar como um *façam para mim*.